# Import module from above directory - Python2

Tags: python, python-import

So here is my tree of files:

```
project/
   moduleToImport.py
   folder1/
      willImport.py
```

I can't import `moduleToImport.py` in my `willImport.py` file.
I execute it like this:

```
usr@machine:~/home$ /test/anotherFolder/project/folder1/willImport.py --args "a" "b" "c"
```

So when I try this solution:

```
from .. import moduleToImport
```

The `willImport.py` file tries to import from `../home` not `/project`, so he can't find the `moduleToImport.py`.

Another solution that I found out there is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/dir")
from app import object
```

But it doesn't work if I use a relative path (which is going to be necessary), like:

```
sys.path.append("..")
from .. import moduleToImport
```

Because it will have the same problem as before: he imports from `../home`.

The main problem is, I can't use an absolute path because it will change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try adding empty `__init__.py` files in each folder?

Comment: add `__init__.py` file in each folder `project` and `folder1` . then from there trying to import  as `from project import moduleToImport`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Folders

```
project/
  moduleToImport.py
  folder1/
    willImport.py
```

### willImport.py

```
import os
import sys

runPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(runPath, ".."))

from moduleToImport import func

func()
```

### moduleToImport.py

```
def func():
    print("Success")
```

### OUTPUT:

```
Success
```

Comment: Edited my last answer cause indeed worked, but now I'm trying to import a simple def from "moduleToImport.py" file. It is just like: def debug(): print "DEBUG", and it says: global name 'debug' is not defined

Comment: I have edited. Can you try again? @ArmandusFiltch

Comment: So, to call this func() in my willImport.py, I will need to import moduleToImport as A, then A.func(), right?

Comment: Yes. If you write **import moduleToImport** you can use **moduleToImport.func()** OR If you write **from moduleToImport import func** you can use **func()** @ArmandusFiltch

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! It worked indeed!